# Is it necessary to be a Christian to be saved?

Tags: soteriology

Is it necessary to have a Christian faith to be saved and not go to hell?

Is it possible for a Muslim to go to heaven?

Or do the bible specifically say that they are all going to hell (Muslims, Jew, Buddhist, Hindu, Non-Believers)?

My question is based on our current teachings (after Christ).

Comment: Not to mention a basic rephrasing of [Do Jewish people go to heaven?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/do-jewish-people-go-to-heaven), [Can an atheist go to heaven?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1809/can-an-atheist-go-to-heaven).  and others.  And I'm sorry, but this is so Fundamental to Christianity that I find it hard to believe this is a real question.  It's like asking "is it necessary to believe in numbers to be a mathematician?"  The idea that Jesus is The way, The truth, and The light is almost universal within Christianity.  It's common knowledge.

Comment: So in short? All people of other religions go to hell?

Comment: ***If Christianity is true, Yes.***  As @caseyr547 stated (and the questions that this is a duplicate of have already covered), according to Christ Himself, anyone who does not have Christ is condemned already. As answered all over the place.  If Christianity is true, then anyone who is not saved by grace through faith in Jesus is doomed to Hell.  If Christianity is not true, then don't worry about it.  But this site isn't here to say what is **True**, just ***what Christianity teaches***.

Comment: that was a different question. No knowledge is different from having a different religion.

Comment: Perhaps, but not having Christ as your Savior is not having Christ as your savior regardless of whether it's through lack of knowledge, atheism, or belief in something else. The answer "yes, Christianity teaches that without Christ, you are lost" ***doesn't change based on why you don't have Christ***.

Comment: Christ is the only way to heaven. But only God knows who is a true Christian. While many, so called, Christians may not make it, some (secret Christian) Muslims may. Remember the Good Samaritan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acts 4:12

> Salvation is found in no one else, for there is no other name under heaven given to mankind by which we must be saved.

Likewise:
John 14:6

> Jesus answered, "I am the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me.

Biblically speaking there is no other way for salvation to occur. Even Jesus asked the Father in Mark 14:36 , if there was any way that he would not have to suffer, to please take that path. There was no other way, and so "For God so loved the world, He gave His only begotten son, that whosoever believes in Him, shall not parish but have everlasting life. For God sent not His son into the world to condemn the world. But that the World may be saved through Him."

Answer (score 2):

> Joh 3:5  Jesus answered, Verily, verily, I say unto thee, Except a man be born of water and of the Spirit, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God.
> Joh 3:6  That which is born of the flesh is flesh; and that which is born of the Spirit is spirit.
> Joh 3:7  Marvel not that I said unto thee, Ye must be born again.
>
> Mar 16:16  He that believeth and is baptized shall be saved; but he that believeth not shall be damned.
>
> Joh 14:6  Jesus saith unto him, I am the way, the truth, and the life: no man cometh unto the Father, but by me.

Yes to go to heaven people must be saved. Jesus is very clear the new birth and believing the Gospel isn't optional. Those who reject the Gospel from any group are damned. It is possible for any person from any group to convert and accept Christ but apart from Christ there is no salvation.

Answer (score 2):

There is much debate on this topic. The following questions are hard to answer:

1. What about those who never heard the Gospel?
2. What about a good man who refused to believe in Christ?
3. What about a pious man from other religion who refuse to accept Christ?

If we hold on to the Biblical truth that ***Jesus Christ is the only way to heaven***, then there is no other choice but to say ***"Anyone who does not believe in Jesus Christ whether they heard it or not will go to Hell!"***

Now how can we reconcile with the fact that God is just?

> Romans 3:23 (NIV) for all have sinned and fall short of the glory of
>   God

We are born with sins. We are all sinners. No one is exempted from sinning.

### Judgement on those who rely on the Law of Moses

Those who put their faith on the Law of Moses will be judged by the same Law. It's impossible for man to follow all the commandments.

> John 5:45 (NIV) “But do not think I will accuse you before the Father.
>   Your accuser is Moses, on whom your hopes are set.

### Judgement on those who heard the gospel

Those who heard the gospel but refused to believe have no excuse but to stay in remorse forever. But who ever believed the Gospel will rejoice in the presence of Jesus because their sins are washed clean by the Blood of Jesus Christ. Not because of their good deeds or piety but because of their faith in His Death and Resurrection.

### Judgement on those who do not have the Law of Moses nor ever heard the Gospel

On the Day of Judgement someone may ask *"God, I was never told about Jesus but I was a good person. I helped many people, I never steal or murder!"* But God will point out all their secret sins and that no one meets the standard of God.

> Romans 2:14-15 (NIV) Indeed, when Gentiles, who do not have the law,
>   do by nature things required by the law, they are a law for
>   themselves, even though they do not have the law. They show that the
>   requirements of **the law are written on their hearts, their consciences
>   also bearing witness, and their thoughts sometimes accusing them** and
>   at other times even defending them.

For this reason Christians are commanded to preach the Gospel to the whole world.

> Matthew 28:19-20 (NIV) Therefore go and make disciples of all nations,
>   baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the
>   Holy Spirit, and teaching them to obey everything I have commanded
>   you. And surely I am with you always, to the very end of the age.