# Does the Church in general need to revisit and revise its strategy in maintaining the faith?

Tags: apologetics

**Is it a high time that we need to impart the young Christians (children) a comprehensive knowledge of all the doctrines of Christianity, or do we tend to raise them as unconvinced Christians susceptible to falter in their faith?**
When a child with an analyzing mind is made to follow a Christian religion but is not made aware of the profound facts about the various beliefs/doctrines of the religion during the catechism classes, he tends to become an unconvinced Christian. When he starts seeking answers to these unconvinced claims from whichever source he finds, he is faced with answers, which sometimes are diametrically opposite to each other, answers that are in confirmation of his belief as well as against it. In absence of right guidance at the time of his growth, some of these young Christians end up in accepting those answers are against the Christian teachings.
**Does the Church in general need to revisit and revise its strategy of adapting to the changed world and change the techniques, to ensure the maintenance of the faith in economically advanced countries?**

Comment: +1 Nice question. Though it could be better worded. I'd suggest replacing that "Do" with "How" and removing the reference to economics. Whys and wherefores of the decline of Christianity in the west could form another question in itself.

Comment: "the profound facts" - I would see part of the problem here coming from conflicting definitions of the word "fact"; by which, all I mean is *evidence*, in terms of critical-thinking / healthy-scepticism, is somewhat ... lacking, for religions in general. I don't mean that as a dig: I just think you'd struggle to fulfil your own aim here, without actively driving away even more analyzing minds, by providing hollow answers.

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't think he's talking about indoctrination or suppression of information critical to Christianity. There are youths that desperately want to get guidance with the problems and issues they face, but feel like they can't fit into the archaic structures and practices. It's the same problem in parenting the young generation, most parents don't know how to connect. I agree it's not perfectly worded but then he's new to the site so give him the benefit of doubt.

Comment: @MonikaMichael oh, I didn't think that either; I was just pointing out a fundamental obstacle in the aims of the central paragraph.

Comment: @Monika ..It is about insufficient knowledge  imparted to the Christian youths. In absence of thorogh knowledge they become suseptible to lose their faith. The youngsters need to be told everything about all the doctrines of Christianity in DETAIL before hand so as to make them resistant to false propaganda.

Comment: Which denomination? The tradition I was raised in does an admirable job of precisely what you describe.

Many others do not.

As it stands, this questions is not answerable.

Comment: @warren... I would realy appreciate your tradition if it does so...may I know your tradition? I my self is from Catholic tradition and finds it greatly lagging in this at least in my region of the world...

Comment: @Joao begging your pardon, but in my case it was doctrine-in-detail that was the **problem**. Vague hand-waving is one thing; when you have the "detail", the cracks and gaps become painfully obvious. My point: adding more detail is not a guaranteed fix.

Comment: Our [faq] leads off with highlighting the importance of questions about **specific doctrines or doctrinal traditions**. Please understand that not all questions that are relevant for Christians to consider are inside the scope of this site. At least the current wording of this particular question runs fairly contrary to what we consider constructive. Rather than asking about Christianity as it is, you are posing a speculative question about what it could/should be. Moreover, you don't specify any particular tradition or doctrinal framework from which you would like to hear.

Comment: This basically turns the question into an open discussion forum. There is going to no basis for judging whether answers are right or wrong, and voting will end up being based on whether or not people agree or disagree. With the many different doctrinal directions people take while claiming the umbrella of "Christianity", this is going to be a mess. If you can re-word this in a way that asks about this issue in a way that will produce verifiable answers based on current the known positions of a specific Christian tradition(s), feel free to edit and flag.

Comment: I would also recommend you take a look at [What makes a good focused question?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/690) when you get a chance for some ideas on what this community has agreed makes for a really good question. We're not looking for perfection, but some effort should be made to work towards those guidelines. Some questions may simply not work here.

Comment: @MarcGravell, Yes, it can definitely go both ways. When we get down to the core bottom (e.g. ["If god  is good why doesn't he heal amputees?" and etc](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/301/102)), the answers to some questions are simply "because God decided that way". Some folks will surely find such an explanation unacceptable and label it as a "crack and gap which will make me refuse to believe"  while some others will find that explanation acceptable. At the end of the day, giving them the full story and **letting them decide for themselves** is better than hiding it from them.

Answer (score 3):

In considering the causes of the lack of in-depth doctrinal and apologetic instruction provided to Christian youth, we might do well to consider the extent to which many, if not the majority of adults who self-identify as Christian are equally untaught.

Some of us are called to in-depth study of the bible; some of us are naturally drawn to a comprehensive study of world religions; some of us are fascinated by human nature, and see the study of religion as providing key historical insights into how the human mind and personality work.

I suspect, however, that the majority of people around the world see the pursuit of entertainment as a more effective use of their spare time, as a way to relax from the stress of life. Add the fact that religious study is -- as with study of most topics -- necessarily academic, and regarded by many as "dry," "stuffy," and even "boring," and one can see how religious study can only be "exciting" to those with a particular way of looking at the world.

This is not to provide an excuse for lack of religious ferver, but simply to acknowledge what, to one way of thinking, is the actual state of things for many.

With reference specifically to Christianity, many would agree heartily with criticism of the instructional methods, or lack thereof, used in many denominations. For example, critical analysis of what is often called the "emergent/emerging church movement" will sometimes describe lack of effective religious instruction as a causal factor in the formation of many of the beliefs espoused by some within the "movement."

All of that being said, I know of no effective ways of resolving the situation. The lack of effective religious instruction of youth can be traced to the lack of effective religious understand in many adults, and is the lack of effective religious understanding in many adults a symptom of anything other than tepid faith -- that is, one that does not present an overwhelming desire to know God, and to [*love God*](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2010:27&version=ESV) with all of one's heart, soul, strength, and mind? Exhortation to a more consuming faith, as an attempt to counter lack of religious ferver, is, after all, among the central topics addressed in scripture.

Comment: @Bunyan..I was wondering whether it is a high time for another event like Vatican-II or something similar where Chrisitians irrespective of denomination and traditions can resort to brainstormming to come with strategies to arrest the decline in faith in economically progressive countries.

Comment: @JoaoRodrigues, I don't think this explains it. Sure, there're many adults who don't have the knowledge to teach, but the question is asking about "for those with the knowledge to teach, why not teach?" And in most churches there would be someone qualified to teach (e.g. pastor etc).