# Apologetic on suffering using a reference to Jesus

Tags: life-of-jesus, suffering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to answer “Why does evil and suffering exist?”](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-to-answer-why-does-evil-and-suffering-exist)

Doing some study at the moment, one of the questions has provoked a few thoughts between me and my wife but we have no answer for this question that satisfies either of us. Any help?

> Using a story or saying from the life of Jesus, give a one-minute
>   reply to the question: "How can you believe in a loving God who allows
>   so much suffering in the world?"

Not the easiest question in the world, but I thought if there was a place that could provide an answer of some variation, this would be it.

Quick note: our answer:

> In John 16:33, Jesus says that there WILL be trouble, but that he has
>   overcome it. He suffered during his illegal trial, punishment and
>   death, but that he came to glory through his resurrection and
>   ascension. I believe not because he allows suffering, but because he
>   suffered for us and because of that resurrection and ascension

Thanks for any other inputs!

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer you the 5 second answer:

**God makes suffering and death holy by suffering and dying Himself.**

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer the philosophical side of this question. Faith or the lack of it rarely rests on pure intellectual reasoning. (Just about every single atheist I know of, when talking about their "conversion" to atheism, has given a testimony about personal experiences, not about a pure intellectual endeavor.)

This question usually burns, because suffering has affected our whole being, not just our logic reasoning capacity.

In the end faith in God is a gift from God. When faced with evil and suffering, the most important thing is that God always brings **hope** into the equation. Without hope, suffering becomes unbearable.

In fact, I think faith in God can help a person to register the pain in ways that otherwise had not been possible. Gods empowerment might not mean that pain goes away, but that we are given courage to *face* it, thus in a strange way initially making it worse!