# Why did God create the great flood?

Tags: flood-of-noah

Why did God create the great flood to wipe the entire human race including unborn children and babies that are probably innocent, and also other species that are innocent?

He can re-create the whole universe and fix his errors of the first creation in just 6 days instead of drowning all creations in 40 days of rain. Why not just make a fresh start.

Comment: Excellent question! - This question is something one might ask when looking at God's destruction of Sodom also. God said he would not destroy it if he found even just 10 righteous in the whole city - then he sent fire down on the city presumably including much more then 10 babies in their cribs. Makes one pause and think about things.

Comment: Nice question, however I do not believe it fits the Stackexchange format and specifically the guidelines of [Christianity SE](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/1381#1381)  You question is searching for Truth.  It is also not scoped within a specific Christian denomination nor is it a broad question about Christianity.

Comment: @DanAndrews Presuming the question is directed at the (majority) parts of Christianity that belief in a flood that exterminated most of mankind, I think that is all the focus this question needs -- there isn't a lot of difference of opinion here that would require further scoping nor is there anything particularly to ask an overview question about.

Comment: This is really just another variation of "If God is omnipotent, and God is good, why didn't He just create a universe where evil is impossible?" a.k.a. the problem of evil.  It's addressed here: [How to answer "Why do evil and suffering exist?"](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/301)

Comment: The title might be nice, but this is the start of a discussion, not a clear question with research effort to back up some of the weird claims.

Comment: What do you mean by re-create whole universe? Start again from scratch, like big bang style? Wouldn't that involve destroying the existing one? How is that better than 40 days of flood?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The flood happened precisely on account of the issues you raise. More specifically, it debunks the premises on which those issues are founded.

As Christians living thousands of years later with only a short Scriptural account to go on, we can really only speculate about how the people of Noah's day must have reasoned with themselves. However it seems likely based on their recorded reactions and God's action that their presuppositions were similar to the ones you have made. They were wrong and the flood was God's way of setting the record straight.

- There is no such thing as "probably innocent". The fallen nature of all humans since Adam means that we are guilty and deserving of condemnation from the womb on. That God could wipe out all humanity in the way he did helps us understands God's disposition towards sin and gives us a reference point for man's sinful nature. The NT echoes this as it affirms that there are NONE righteous on their own apart from God's intervention. The pre-flood people of earth are used as a reminder of this and the flood stands of a warning of the future judgement we will all face.
- It wasn't God's mistake in the first place that he would need to "fix his error". The error lies with man - who chose to rebel rather than obey - but the solution cannot come from man, it must be directed by God. It was God that preserved Noah. It is God that will preserve some men (those who by faith in Him come under his saving grace).
- God didn't mess up that would need to start over, it was always his plan to redeem creation. He knew what would happen to it, but entered into a covenant with himself - God the Son agreeing to be the ransom, the redeemer to purchase a people out from God the Father's righteously judgement. The concept of redemption was always part of the plan. Likewise we look forward to a new heavens and a new earth -- not a different creation entirely but a re-creation -- a redemption of creation itself on the day where he will make all things new (after he finally judges those who do not have faith in him).
- Other species are not innocent. All of creation was subjected to the fall. The caretaker of creation - the priest who's job it was to mediate between God and creation - the one who was charged with naming and caring for all the species - fell down on the job. He left his job unfinished. As a result of his failure, not only was he himself cursed but everything in his domain was cursed as well. The ground brought forth weeds and thorns. The animal kingdom was subjected to the same futility that mankind was now under.

The exact "why" if many of God's choices is not fully revealed to us, but Christians use God's actions in the past to help shape their understanding of the present. The flood helps reset our understanding of what guilt and innocence mean in relation to a holy God. It teaches us significant lessons about the nature of man, creation and God himself. It warns us against evil and points us toward salvation.

Comment: you said it was always his plan? does it mean that he knows that if he give freedom to man they will soon be sinners and soon he have to kill them? so it was all planned? why not just create a new bunch without the original sin? therefore he won't need hell to torture people. he knew people will be sinners and still he proceed with the creation. it's kinda doesn't make sense...

Comment: "Other species are not innocent". How did this happened? adam and eve ate the forbidden fruit and even the lions and and rabbits and every living species become sinners? i don't understand and it doesn't even make sense

Comment: In 1 Corinthians 13 it says Love keeps no record of wrongs, so does your first point mean that god does not love us? It does not make sense

Comment: @FFCoder - welcome to the site! Some of your arguments make good sense in a way but they are really new questions. Caleb already answered the first one. You might want to read the FAQ about how things work here. The format is basically Q&A, without trying to engage in arguments. To create an argument one needs to answer someone else's question. Then the community votes on how well the argument was made, if it really represents a common view and/or if it uses good references to document that view. Cheers.

Comment: @FFCoder God does not delight in punishing people, yet He does not force people to return His love.  Hell is the place where God is not.  For those who have reject God, it would seem to be a punishment to make them be with God forever.  So, God does not do this, but gives them a place where He is not because of their choice.  God has extended His love to all people and desires that all would come to Him.  In fact, God has payed the penalty and the debts for all wrongs, yet again, He does not force people to love Him against their will.

Comment: @FFCoder I believed it was all planned by God himself. We are in a phase of test and if we passed, we are moved on to the next stage - heaven/new world. The ones that failed will be destroyed (hell fire, etc). We are pawns in this game, valuable pawns - Why was Jesus(the Lamb) killed before the foundation of the earth (Read that in Revelation)