# What is the purpose of Evil and Sin?

Tags: good-and-evil

If God can do everything than, why don't he just abolish sin and evil from the world. As if it never existed? There's no reason to have sin and evil running around if the lord finds it sickening why must it exist? Is evil and sin some force above God's power?

Comment: See also [How to answer “Why do evil and suffering exist?”](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-to-answer-why-do-evil-and-suffering-exist)

Comment: By the way, welcome to the site! Don't take the closing of this question as a discouragement. As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: @Potatofactory Please see also: [Evil | New Advent](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/05649a.htm), if you mind is in the mood for heavy lifting.